# Form action file format in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I Have:

I have Index.html in that there are 4 form elements are there(all are text and one drop down is there)

Whenever user enter submit then the data will displayed on confirm.html using another js file in formatting some operations then displayed in confirm.html
[like this data will be shown][1]

What I want is:

I have to create all the menus in this confirm.html too.
whenever I'm trying to do(defining div in confirm.html its doesn't show anything)

this is the confirm.html file:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calculate.js"> 
    </script>   
    </head>            
    <body onload="init();">
    <div id="Menu">        
    </div>           
    </body>        
    </html>
this is calculate.js(displying data on confirm.html)
// Called on body's `onload` event

    var cumulative=0;
     function init() {

      var salary = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("salary"));
      var percent = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("percent"));
      var age = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("age"));
      var rAge = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("rAge"));
      var sel = localStorage.getItem("sel");

      var roundedSalary = parseInt(Math.ceil((salary + 2000) / 1000) * 1000); //Doing Rounding for basic column Display
      var basic;
      var factor = 0;
      var biWeekly = 0, monthly = 0,annual = 0;


      //Displaying Headers
      document.write("<head>");
      document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"confirm.css\">");
      document.write("<title>Result</title>");
      document.write("</head>");
      document.write("<body>");

     /* document.write("<center>")
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

      if (dd < 10) {
       dd = '0' + dd
      }

      if (mm < 10) {
       mm = '0' + mm
      }
      today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
      document.write("<h1>" + "FEGLI CALCULATIONS ON" + "&nbsp;" + today + "</h1>");
      document.write("</center>")
      */


      document.write("<table><tr><th>&nbsp;Age&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Annual-Salary&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;BiWeekly-Premium&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Monthly-Premium&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Annual-Premium&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Cumulative-Premium&nbsp;</th><th>Basic&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Total&nbsp;</th></tr>");
      basic = parseInt(roundedSalary * calculateFactor(age));
      //document.write("roundedSalary"+roundedSalary+"calculateFactor"+calculateFactor(age));
      premium = calculateBiweekly(salary, basic, age, rAge);
      biWeekly = premium[0];
      monthly = premium[1];
      annual = premium[2];
      cumulative = premium[3];
      if(sel==="no")
      {
          alert(age);
      document.write("<tr><td>" + age + "/" + (age + 1) + "</td><td>" + "$" + salary.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + "$" + biWeekly.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + "$" + monthly.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + "$" + annual.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + "$" + cumulative.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + "$" + basic + "</td><td>-</td></tr>");
      }
      else{

          //alert(age);
          document.write("<tr><td>" + age + "/" + (age + 1) + "</td><td>" + "$" + salary.toFixed(2) + "</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>" + "$" + basic + "</td><td>-</td></tr>");
      }


      salary = parseFloat(salary);

      for (var i = age + 1; i < 101; i++) {
       document.write("<tr>");
       document.write("<td>" + i + "/" + (i + 1) + "</td>");

       if (i < rAge) {

        salary = salary + (salary * percent);

        roundedSalary = parseInt(Math.ceil((salary + 2000) / 1000) * 1000);
        //          document.write("age"+i+"roundedSalary"+roundedSalary+"<br>");
        document.write("<td>" + "$" + salary.toFixed(2) + "</td>");
       } else {
        salary = 0;
        document.write("<td>-</td>");
       }



       basic = parseInt(roundedSalary * calculateFactor(i));

       premium = calculateBiweekly(salary, basic, i);
       biWeekly = premium[0];
       monthly = premium[1];
       annual = premium[2];
       cumulative = premium[3];

       document.write("<td>" + "$" + biWeekly.toFixed(2) + "</td>");
       document.write("<td>" + "$" + monthly.toFixed(2) + "</td>");
       document.write("<td>" + "$" + annual.toFixed(2) + "</td>");
       document.write("<td>" + "$" + cumulative.toFixed(2) + "</td>");

       document.write("<td>" + "$" + basic + "</td>");
       document.write("<td>-</td>");
       document.write("</tr>");
     }
      document.write("</table>");
      document.write("</body>")
     }
     function calculateFactor(age) {
      var factor = 0;
      if (age > 35 && age < 45) {


       switch (age) {


        case 36:
         factor = 1.9;
         break;

        case 37:
         factor = 1.8;
         break;

        case 38:
         factor = 1.7;
         break;

        case 39:
         factor = 1.6;
         break;

        case 40:
         factor = 1.5;
         break;

        case 41:
         factor = 1.4;
         break;

        case 42:
         factor = 1.3;
         break;

        case 43:
         factor = 1.2;
         break;

        case 44:
         factor = 1.1;
         break;


       }
      } else if (age <= 35) {
       factor = 2;
      } else if (age >= 45) {
       factor = 1;
      }

      return factor;
     }

     function calculateBiweekly(salary, basic, age) {
      var biWeekly = 0;

      if (salary > 0) {

       biWeekly = ((basic / calculateFactor(age)) * 0.15) / 1000;
       monthly = ((basic / calculateFactor(age)) * 0.325) / 1000;



      } else if (salary == 0 && age <= 65) {



       biWeekly = ((basic / calculateFactor(age)) * (2.455 / 2.166)) / 1000;
       monthly = ((basic / calculateFactor(age)) * (2.455)) / 1000;


      } else if (salary == 0 && age > 65) {

       //document.write("age"+age+"salary"+salary+"<br>");
       biWeekly = ((basic / calculateFactor(age)) * (2.13 / 2.166)) / 1000;
       monthly = ((basic / calculateFactor(age)) * (2.13)) / 1000;


      }
       annual = 12 * monthly;
    cumulative = cumulative+annual;
      //document.write("cumulative"+cumulative+"<br>");

      return [biWeekly, monthly, annual, cumulative];
     }// Called on body's `onload` event


This file validating user forms(according to my needs)
valid.js
function Validation()
{

    var salary=document.getElementById("salary").value;
    var percent=document.getElementById("percent").value/100;
    var age=document.getElementById("age").value;
    var rAge=document.getElementById("rAge").value;
    var sel=document.getElementById("sel").value;       


            // Storing the value above into localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("salary", salary);
            localStorage.setItem("percent", percent);
            localStorage.setItem("age", age);
            localStorage.setItem("rAge", rAge);
            localStorage.setItem("sel", sel);



    if(salary=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="**Please Enter the Annual Salary**";
        return false;

    }


    if(isNaN(salary))
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML= "**Do not Accept Characters**";
        return false;

    }

    if( percent=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="**Please Enter the  Annual Salary Increase**";
        return false;

    }           

    if(isNaN( percent))
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML= "**Do not Accept Characters**";
        return false;

    }       

    if(age=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="**Please Enter the your Age**";
        return false;

    }


    if(age<24 || Page>65)
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="** Present Age Starts from 24 up to 65**";
        return false;


    }


    if(isNaN(age))
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML= "**Do not Accept Characters**";
        return false;

    }


    if(rAge=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="**Please Enter the Retirement Age**";
        return false;

    }


    if(age>rAge)
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="**Retirement Age Must Be Greater Than Your Age**";
        return false;

    }

    if(rAge<24 || rAge>101)
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="** Retirement Age Starts from 24 up to 101**";
        return false;

    }

    if(isNaN(rAge))
    {
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML= "**Do not Accept Characters**";
        return false;

    }




}
```

style.css:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .Bgimg {
        background-image: url('file:///C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/WEB%20PROJECTS/bg03.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 110%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .Menu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    .leftmenu {
        width: 20%;
        line-height: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
    .leftmenu h4 {
        padding-left: 70px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    .rightmenu {
        width: 60%;
        height: 100px;
        float: right; 
    }
    .rightmenu ul {
        margin-left: 100px;

    }
    .rightmenu ul li {
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    .search{
        width:20%;
        height:100px;
        float:right;
    }
    .search form{
        line-height:100px;
        float:right;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    #firstlist {
        color: orange;
    }
    .rightmenu ul li:hover {
        color: orange;
    }
    .Bground{
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background-color:#786966;
    }
    .Bground h4{
        color:#DAF7A6;
        font-size:30px;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #hi{
        width:100%;
        height:400px;
        background-color:#581845;
    }
    #hi form{
        padding-top:50px;
    }
    .service{
        width:100%;
        height:400px;
        background-color:orange;
    }
    .service h4{
        font-size:40px;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #user{
        font-weight:bold;
        color:red;
        font-size:20px;
    }
    .text {
        width: 100%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: left;
        color: white;
        height: 20px;
    }
    .text h1 {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
    }
    input[type=text],select{
        height: 25px;
        width:150px;
        border:3px solid blue;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    input[type=submit]{
        height: 30px;
        width:100px;
        color:white;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color:red;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:15px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    input[type=text]:hover{
        border:2px solid black;

    }
    .tble{
        border:2px solid white;
        padding-bottom:1px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    #Buttonone {
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 40px;
        border: none;
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        border: 3px solid white;
    }
    #Buttontwo {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 40px;
        border: 3px solid white;
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
```

Index.html:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

     </head>
       <body>
          <!--
             <div class="Bgimg">
             -->
          <!-- this div for  menu-->
          <div class="Menu">
             <!-- this div for left menu-->
             <div class="leftmenu">
                <h4>FEGLI</h4>
             </div>
             <!-- this div for right menu-->
             <div class="rightmenu">
                <ul>
                   <li id="firstlist">Home</li>
                   <li>Services</li>
                   <li>About</li>
                   <li>Contact</li>
                   <li>Blog</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="search">
                <form  action="/action_page.php" >
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" size="20">
                   <input  type="submit"></button>
                </form>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Bground">
             <h4>Fegli Calculator</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="hi">

             <form action="confirm.html"  onsubmit="return Validation();" >

                <center>

                   <table class="tble" align="center"  cellspacing = "20">
                   <span id="user"> </span>
                      <tbody>

                         <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif"><font color="white" size="4px" ><b>Annual Salary</b></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#666666" size="4px" ><b> : </b></font></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="10"  autocomplete="off" id="salary" /></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif"><font color="white" size="4px" ><b>Annual Sal Increse</b></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#666666" size="4px" ><b> : </b></font></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="rdate" value="" size="10"  autocomplete="off" id="percent" /></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif"><font color="white" size="4px" ><b>Your Present Age</b></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#666666" size="4px" ><b> : </b></font></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="rdate" value="" size="10"  autocomplete="off" id="age" /></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif"><font color="white" size="4px" ><b>Retirement Age</b></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#666666" size="4px" ><b> : </b></font></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="rdate" value="" size="10"  autocomplete="off" id="rAge" /></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif"><font color="white" size="4px"><b>Postal Employee</b></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#666666" size="4px" ><b> : </b></font></td>
                            <td>
                               <select id="sel">
                                  <option value="yes" >Yes</option>
                                  <option value="no" >No</option>
                               </select>
                            <td>
                         </tr>
                   </Table>
                   <B>
                      <center><input type="submit"></center>
                   </B>
                   <br>
             </form>
             </center>
          </div>
          <div class="service">
             <h4> Our Services </h4>
             <div class="Serv"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer"></div>
          <!--
             </div>

             -->
       </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUuJa.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you selected "Menu" as if it was a class

```
.Menu {
   //code
}
```

but it should be accessed using a pound sign (#)

```
#Menu{
   //code
}
```